# how can I put a document.addEventListener("scroll") in other file to call it in my component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have this code with which I can check when the `bottom` of a `div` is reached by `scrolling`:

```
const checkBottomDiv = (el: HTMLElement) => {
  return el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - 400 <= window.innerHeight;
};

const contentArticleId = document.getElementById("myDiv") as HTMLElement;

const trackScrolling = () => {
  callback();

  if (checkBottomDiv(contentArticleId)) {
    console.log("bottomDiv");
    document.removeEventListener("scroll", trackScrolling);
  }
};
document.addEventListener("scroll", trackScrolling);
```

I would like to reuse this functionality in other `components` and for this reason, I would like to put this logic in a separate function and then call it (`function.ts`).

I am doing this:

```
app.tsx.  //component

useEffect(() => {
  let element = document.getElementById("myDiv") as HTMLElement;
  trackScrolling(element, callback);
})


function.ts. //function file

const checkBottomDiv = (el: HTMLElement) => {
  return el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - 400 <= window.innerHeight;
};

export const trackScrolling = (element: HTMLElement, callback: () => void) => {
  if (checkBottomDiv(element)) {
    callback();
    document.removeEventListener("scroll", trackScrolling);
  }
};
document.addEventListener("scroll", trackScrolling);
```

but I get errors that I don't know how to fix.

this is my live code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-solomon-hu3e3

what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it.

Comment: You should consider using an [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) for this instead of listening for scroll events.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can, you may actually not want to do it this way. A better approach would involve attaching the event listener inside the componentDidMount lifecycle or the useEffect hook.
This translates to the following code:

```
const MyWrapperComponent = (props) => {
  useEffect(()=>{
    document.addEventListener('scroll', (e)=>{
       // do something
    });
    return ()=>{
      document.removeEventListener("scroll");
    }
  },[]);
}
```

But since you want to use the scroll event in many components putting this useEffect hook inside all of them will spaghettify your code, so to avoid this, you can make use of the context API to share the event data with all the components that needs it.

Comment: thanks, but is this line correct?       document.removeEventListener("scroll");?

Answer (score 0):

Your `document.addEventListener("scroll", trackScrolling);` is not inside of the `trackScrolling` function. You'll want to move that inside of the function body so that it has access to the `callback`. Your code should look like this:

```js
export const trackScrolling = (element: HTMLElement, callback: () => void) => {
  if (element && checkBottomDiv(element)) {
    callback();
    document.removeEventListener("scroll", trackScrolling);
  }
  document.addEventListener("scroll", trackScrolling);
};
```

Also, when writing custom functionality for React like this, if the logic depends on a hook (like `useEffect`), it can be cleaner to include the hook in the custom function as well. For example, you might want something more like this:

```js
app.tsx.  //component

useTrackScrolling("myDiv", callback);


function.ts. //function file

const checkBottomDiv = (el: HTMLElement) => {
  return el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - 400 <= window.innerHeight;
};

export const useTrackScrolling = (id: string, callback: () => void) => {
  const element = document.getElementById(id) as HTMLElement;

  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = () => {
      if (element && checkBottomDiv(element)) {
        callback();
        document.removeEventListener("scroll", listener);
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener("scroll", listener);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("scroll", listener);
  }, [element, callback]);
};
```

That's just my opinion though, you can write your code however you prefer :)

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getBoundingClientRect')

Comment: This means the element is null, which can happen either if the id passed is wrong or if the element simply hasn't been rendered on the page yet. I edited my answer to make sure the element exists before checking its bounding rect.